# WSO2 Identity Server fails to perform authentication SAML2.0 when consumer URL inaccessible

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server fails to perform authentication SAML2.0 consumer URL not reachable

We are using WSO2 Identity Server 4.6.0 for SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On.

The authentication was working fine when the Assertion Consumer URL of the service provider was directly "accessible" (network connectivity) from the WSO2 IS node.

However, I get an error if I register a New Service Provider with an Assertion Consumer

URL which is not directly reachable from the Identity provider : WSO2 IS , but accessible

from the requesting user agent i.e. browser.

- The User Agent request gets redirectd to the WSO2 IS (login,do?SAMLRequest=nZP... )
- But the POST /commonauth failed with the following returned Status code 302 and Location header Location: authenticationendpoint/samlsso_notification.do?status=Error when processing the authentication request!&statusMsg=The message was not recognized by the SAML 2.0 SSO Provider. Please check the logs for more details

For example the Assertion Consumer URL provisionned was refering to a private ip address only accessible from the requesting browser).

I also tried to provide a hostname instead without success.

### Here below is the error we get from the WSO2 IS logs :

TID: [0] [IS] [2014-06-10 17:54:52,344] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet} -  The value of sessionDTO is null. This could be due to the hostname settings {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet}

### From the browser :

SAML2.0 based Single Sign On

Any idea why the autentication request failed and why the SSO provider complains about "unrecognized message".

Thanks for your support

JS

Answer (score 0):

If you have fronted Identity server with a proxy server or load balancer Please try to configure severs proxy configurations.
[1] http://soasecurity.org/2014/04/11/handling-server-redirects-when-it-is-a-proxy/